Azure Batch [Python] - DeserializationError: TaskAddParameter has no attribute lower()
Using python to organise batch tasks, where the container takes in a list of file paths, pulls the files and passes them through a container.
When starting tasks I get the following error:
2024-04-22T08:48:31.937977+0100 | ERROR    | Unexpected error when adding tasks: 
('Unable to build a model: ("Unable to deserialize to object: type, AttributeError: \'TaskAddParameter\' object has no attribute \'lower\'", 
AttributeError("\'TaskAddParameter\' object has no attribute \'lower\'")), 
DeserializationError: ("Unable to deserialize to object: type, AttributeError: \'TaskAddParameter\' object has no attribute \'lower\'", 
AttributeError("\'TaskAddParameter\' object has no attribute \'lower\'"))', 
DeserializationError("Unable to deserialize to object: type, 
AttributeError: 'TaskAddParameter' object has no attribute 'lower'", 
AttributeError("'TaskAddParameter' object has no attribute 'lower'")))

The rest of my code for creating pools & jobs etc wroks fine.
This is the portion of my code resposible for creating tasks:
    def create_task(self):

        files_to_process = []

        registry_server = self.config.REGISTRY_LOGIN_SERVER
        container_name = self.args.container_name
        container_version = self.args.container_version

        if os.path.isdir(self.args.files):
            for file in os.listdir(self.args.files):
                if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(self.args.files, file)):
                    files_to_process.append(os.path.join(self.args.files, file))
        else:
            files_to_process.append(self.args.files)

        tasks = []

        for i, file_name in enumerate(files_to_process, start=1):

            task_name = f"{self.args.task_prefix}-{self.config.REGISTRY_NAME}-{str(i)}".lower()

            logger.debug("Adding task: " + task_name)

            task_container_settings = TaskContainerSettings(
                image_name=f"{registry_server}/{container_name}:{container_version}", # This is the container image
                container_run_options=f"--env FILES={file_name}"
            )

            if not isinstance(task_name, str) or not isinstance(file_name, str):
                logger.error(f"Type error in task parameters: {task_name}, {file_name}")
                continue  # Skip this iteration if there's a type mismatch

            task = TaskAddParameter(
                id=task_name,
                command_line="/bin/bash -c 'echo Starting task; ./entrypoint.sh'",
                container_settings=task_container_settings
            )

            logger.debug("TaskAddParameter details: ID={}, CommandLine={}, ContainerSettings={}".format(
                task.id, task.command_line, task.container_settings
            ))

            tasks.append(task)

            try:
                logger.info(f"Adding {len(tasks)} tasks to job '{self.last_job_name}'...")
                self.batch_client.task.add(self.last_job_name, tasks)
                logger.info(f"Tasks added to job '{self.last_job_name}'")

            except BatchErrorException as e:
                logger.error(f"Failed to add tasks to job '{self.last_job_name}': {e}")
                exit()

            except Exception as e:
                logger.error(f"Unexpected error when adding tasks: {e}")
                exit()

        pass

Here is the console output for the the snippet below:
2024-04-22T08:48:31.856327+0100 | INFO     | Attempting to create job '2024-04-22-08-48-29-test-'...
2024-04-22T08:48:31.935065+0100 | INFO     | Created job '2024-04-22-08-48-29-test-'
2024-04-22T08:48:31.936087+0100 | DEBUG    | Adding task: 2024-04-22-08-48-29-test-1
2024-04-22T08:48:31.936981+0100 | DEBUG    | TaskAddParameter details: ID=2024-04-22-08-48-29-test-1, CommandLine=/bin/bash -c 'echo Starting task; ./entrypoint.sh', ContainerSettings={'additional_properties': {}, 'container_run_options': '--env FILES=.\\test-files\\bc_train_batch-0.txt', 'image_name': 'XXX.azurecr.io/sequencer:latest', 'registry': None, 'working_directory': None}
2024-04-22T08:48:31.936981+0100 | INFO     | Adding 1 tasks to job '2024-04-22-08-48-29-test-'...
2024-04-22T08:48:31.937977+0100 | ERROR    | Unexpected error when adding tasks: ('Unable to build a model: ("Unable to deserialize to object: type, AttributeError: \'TaskAddParameter\' object has no attribute \'lower\'", AttributeError("\'TaskAddParameter\' object has no attribute \'lower\'")), DeserializationError: ("Unable to deserialize to object: type, AttributeError: \'TaskAddParameter\' object has no attribute \'lower\'", AttributeError("\'TaskAddParameter\' object has no attribute \'lower\'"))', DeserializationError("Unable to deserialize to object: type, AttributeError: 'TaskAddParameter' object has no attribute 'lower'", AttributeError("'TaskAddParameter' object has no attribute 'lower'")))

I had a look at related issues with msrest (listed below) but could not solve the issue
Azure SDK Docs
Git Hub Issues #1
Git Hub Issues #2


Azure Batch [Python] - DeserializationError: TaskAddParameter has no attribute lower()

The above error occurred is due to when data is being deserialized, it may contain unexpected values or types, or it may not fit the intended structure. Try with the below code, it contains logging initialization at the start In order to guarantee that you have logging throughout the execution. To monitor the program's flow and observe the condition of the objects at various points in time, debugging statements are used.
class TaskManager:
    def __init__(self, batchClient, config, args):
        self.batch_client = batchClient
        self.config = config
        self.args = args
        self.lastJobName = None

    def create_task(self):
        logger = logging.getLogger(__module1__)

        files_to_process = []

        registry_server = self.config.REGISTRY_LOGIN_SERVER
        containerName = self.args.containerName
        containerVersion = self.args.containerVersion

        if os.path.isdir(self.args.files):
            for file1 in os.listdir(self.args.files):
                if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(self.args.files, file1)):
                    files_to_process.append(os.path.join(self.args.files, file1))
        else:
            files_to_process.append(self.args.files)

        for i, file1 in enumerate(files_to_process, start=1):
            task1 = f"{self.args.task_prefix}-{self.config.REGISTRY_NAME}-{str(i)}".lower()

            logger.debug("Adding task: " + task1)

            task_container_settings = TaskContainerSettings(
                image1=f"{registry_server}/{containerName}:{containerVersion}",
                container_run_options=f"--env FILES={file1}"
            )

            try:
                task = TaskAddParameter(
                    id=task1,
                    command_line="/bin/bash -c 'echo Starting task; ./entrypoint.sh'",
                    container_settings=task_container_settings
                )

                logger.debug("TaskAddParameter details: ID={}, CommandLine={}, ContainerSettings={}".format(
                    task.id, task.command_line, task.container_settings
                ))

                logger.info(f"Adding task {task.id} to job '{self.lastJobName}'...")
                self.batch_client.task.add(self.lastJobName, task)
                logger.info(f"Task {task.id} added to job '{self.lastJobName}'")

            except BatchErrorException as e:
                logger.error(f"Failed to add tasks to job '{self.lastJobName}': {e}")
                exit()

            except Exception as e:
                logger.error(f"Unexpected error when adding tasks: {e}")
                logger.exception("Exception occurred")
                exit()

Output:
INFO     | Attempting to create job '2024-05-03-12-00-00-test-'
INFO     | Created job '2024-05-03-12-00-00-test-'
DEBUG    | Adding task: 2024-05-03-12-00-00-test-1
DEBUG    | TaskAddParameter details: ID=2024-05-03-12-00-00-test-1, CommandLine=/bin/bash -c 'echo Starting task; ./entrypoint.sh', ContainerSettings={'additional_properties': {}, 'container_run_options': '--env FILES=./test-files/bc_train_batch-0.txt', 'image1': 'XXX.azurecr.io/sequencer:latest', 'registry': None, 'working_directory': None}
INFO     | Adding 1 tasks to job '2024-05-03-12-00-00-test-'
INFO     | Tasks added to job '2024-05-03-12-00-00-test-'


Check this document for more information.

